# Can Java 10 type inference for local variables infer void?

Tags: java, type-inference, java-10

With Java 10, we can use type inference.

```
String s1 = "hello"; // before Java 10
var s2 = "hello"; // now
```

However, there is one thing which we couldn't do before: have variables of type **void**.

So, in previous versions we simply couldn't define the variable type `void`. But now we can assign result of method returning `void` to the variable:

```
void emptyMethod() { }
...

void v1 = emptyMethod(); // won't compile
var v2 = emptyMethod(); // no problem at all
```

The question is - why does it even compile, what purpose does it serve? Do you have any use case for this strange thing?

Variable of type `void` has no methods, it cannot be even used as a parameter of a method.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why do you think it compiles? It doesn't compile:

```
> javac Main.java
Main.java:5: error: cannot infer type for local variable v2
        var v2 = emptyMethod(); // no problem at all
            ^
  (variable initializer is 'void')
1 error
```

You probably use IntelliJ IDEA, do you? IDEA currently does not detect such kind of an error. There is a bug for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188623

Comment: @berry120 Since the `private` `Void` constructor doesn’t throw anything (in the book Effective Java an `AssertionError` is suggested), one can create instances of `Void` using reflection.

Comment: @Martin Just as I'd stopped putting "reflection hacks aside" on such comments, someone has to step in and show the need for it again!

Comment: This shows the advantage of eclipse's approach, they tap into their own java compiler to generate errors in the IDE, so it is always consistent with actual compiler results.